I think my dog is MAD not SAD
I have a 6 yr old rescue dachshund/chihuahua mix. There was a medical emergency in my family and I had to leave him for a month. He stayed home with the other 5 family members I live with and all adore him. They kept telling me how sad he was at my absence. I got home today and he doesn't seem sad to me. He seems mad. Standoffish. Won't look at me. Won't sit on my lap etc. Feel like I need to make amends to him. What do I do? ps: he does have SEVERE separation anxiety, even if I'm gone less than an hour.

I agree with keshlam. The more you "make amends" or otherwise act different around him, the more you signal to him that whatever happened is extremely special and absolutely requires special behavior. By doing so you can unintentionally increase his separation anxiety.
Instead you should act as normal as possible, just the way you would have acted if you never left. Pet him if he comes to you, but don't try to call him and make him sit on your lap.
The other members of your family should also follow the same advice. No extra cuddles or "Oh look there's Eleanor, aren't you happy to see them?". They should act as if nothing ever happened.
Your dog will probably need a few days to get back to normal. Give him the time he needs by not forcing him into any behavior, but welcome him if he comes to you.

He'll get over it. Give him a few days and he'll forget that he's annoyed you went away.
